# AccessDeniedException while running Files.walkFileTree

Tags: java, exception, filepath, ioexception

I am trying to walk through the folders and sub-folders using `walkFileTree` and I am using Java 7. I am getting `AccessDeniedException`. I tried @Override for `visitFileFailed` and changed the definition. It did not work.

```
public void getAllDirectories(File file) {

    try {
        final java.nio.file.Path p = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());

        Files.walkFileTree(p, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {

                try {
                    File f = file.toFile();

                    if (f.isDirectory()) {
                        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
                        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException e) {

                _log.warn("Access Permissions denied for " + file);
                return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
            }
        });
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.prinln("Error Caught: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In the above code, instead of handling `AccessPermissionDenied` exception by `visitFileFailed` method, it is throwing an exception and `getAllDirectories` method is catching and printing the output as:

```
Error Caught:java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: file_path
```

Error is Something like this:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: file_path
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsDirectoryStream.<init>(WindowsDirectoryStream.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:518)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:300)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.next(FileTreeWalker.java:372)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2706)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:232)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: Actual stack trace please. Meaning something like `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: This code misses a return statement in visitFile(). Please post a minimal working example.

Comment: Updated. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: _Probably unrelated_: (1) The `Path` will never be a directory inside the `visitFile` method (see `preVisitDirectory` and `postVisitDirectory`). (2) You can test if a `Path` is a directory with `Files.isDirectory(Path)`. In this case, however, you could just query `BasicFileAttributes.isDirectory()`. (3) Returning `SKIP_SUBTREE` only has meaning when returned from `preVisitDirectory`. When returned from the other three `FileVisitor` methods it's the same as `CONTINUE`.

Comment: I was able to run your code and get the message ("Access Permissions denied for X:\testing\dirA\dirB") from the following statement when there is a directory in the file tree which had all permissions set as "Denied" on my Windows laptop: 
`_log.warn("Access Permissions denied for " + file);`. The code worked as expected, I think.

Comment: It is working in local, but when deployed on servers, it is throwing the error

Comment: The exception might be given to `postVisitDirectory` rather than `visitFileFailed`. Try overriding the former as well to handle the `IOException` (if present).